# Why value does not change of string when i pass it to method

Tags: java, string

Sorry this look very childish question .But why my String value is not changing. my code is below

```
class Car{

public static void car(String name)
{
name="Bmw";
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    

String name="honda";

Car.car(name);

System.out.println(name);
    }

out put:-honda
```

I know java is pass by value . so i was thinking that `honda` will become `bmw`. Please give explaination on this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: The explanation is in your question: Java uses pass-by-value. All you're doing in your `car` function is changing the value in the `name` **parameter** within the `car` function. That has no effect (and *can* have no effect) on the `name` **variable** in `main`.

Comment: If you know java is pass-by-value, why do you think honda has to became bmv?

Comment: I was thinking honda will be passed . and name will be changed to bmw .

Comment: Read the upvoted answers in the linked original. They answer this in detail.

Comment: @FaisalAhmed, it is not logical, this behaviour you described should be in "pass-by-reference" scenario

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. `name="Bmw"` does not *modify* the original string, it assigns a *new* string to the `name` variable, and since arguments are passed by value, the new value is invisible to the caller.

Comment: Thanks friends i understood concept now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854909/can-fonts-and-its-size-can-be-changed-from-xml-in-android can anyone help me on this